# Quando é necessário usar GC.Collect()?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, gerenciamento-de-memória, garbage-collector

Sei que no .NET/CLR, o *garbage collector* age sozinho, sem que seja necessário chamá-lo manualmente.

Existem casos em que o *garbage collector* não "coleta" automaticamente? Quando é necessário usar o `GC.Collect()`?